# How to print a rectangle of asterisks in C++

Tags: c++

I have been told to ask the user to input how many rows and columns for a rectangle they would like to print and in what symbol they want it. I am unaware as to how to do this and all my google searching only got me as far as printing one row. Directions dictate that the rows should be 3 and the columns should be 7 with the character '$'. I'm still a beginner so please go easy on me. This is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void PrintChar(int row = 5, int column = 10, char symbol = '*');

int main()
{
    int rows, columns;
    char symbol;

    cout << "How many rows and columns do you want, and with what symbol (default     is *) ?" << endl;
    cin >> rows >> columns >> symbol;

    PrintChar(rows, columns, symbol);

}

void PrintChar(int row, int column, char symbol)
{

    for (int y = 1; y <= column; y++)
    {
        cout << symbol;
}
```

That prints out a full line of the symbol and that's where my thinking stops. If you could help me with the final rows, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You just need two nested for loops: `for (int r = 1; r <= rows; ++r) { for (int c = 1; c <= columns; ++c) cout << symbol; cout << '\n'; }`

Comment: You have a for loop for the columns but not for the rows. Add another loop inside your current for loop for the rows and it should work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. Added a newline to make it look like a rectangle.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void PrintChar(int row = 5, int column = 10, char symbol = '*');

int main() {

    int rows, columns;
    char symbol;

    cout << "How many rows and columns do you want, and with what symbol (default     is *) ?" << endl;
    cin >> rows >> columns >> symbol;

    PrintChar(rows, columns, symbol);

    return(0);

}

void PrintChar(int row, int column, char symbol) {
    for (int y = 1; y <= column; y++) {
        for (int x = 1; x <= row; x++) {
            cout << symbol;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: ...and it seems someone has beat me to it. :/

Comment: Thank you very much. I should have been able to get that. For some reason I just could not. You're a good man.

Answer (score 2):

- First, `int main()` should have a `return` statement.
- There should be 2 nested for loops inside PrintChar, outer one for the rows and inner one for the columns, like:-

  for (int x = 1; x <= rows; x++)
  {
    cout << endl;
    for (int y = 1; y <= columns; y++)
    {
      cout << symbol;
    }
  }

Comment: "First, int main() should have a return statement." - that's only needed in C.  `for (int x = 1; x <= rows; x++) { cout << endl; for (int y = 1; y <= columns; y++) { cout << symbol; } }` prints a newline before the first row and not after the last (and flushes unnecessarily often).

Answer (score 1):

Using nested loop you can achieve that.

```
void PrintChar(int row, int column, char symbol)
{

    for (int x = 0; x < row; x++)
    {
       for (int y = 1; y <= column; y++)
       {
           cout << symbol;
       }
       cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems as a [basic star patterns looping exercise](http://codeforwin.blogspot.in/2015/07/square-star-pattern-in-c.html). Use nested loops to print the required pattern

```
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)  
{  
    for(j=1; j<=m; j++)  
    {  
        cout<<"*";  
    }  
    cout<<"\n";  
}
```

Here `n` is the number of rows and `m` is number of columns each row.